# Go race condition in timeout handler

Tags: http, go, race-condition

I can see two main issues in the example code below, but I don't know how to solve them correctly.

If the timeout handler does not get the signal through the errCh that the next handler has completed or an error occured, it will reply "408 Request timeout" to the request.

The problem here is that the ResponseWriter is not safe to be used by multiple goroutines. And the timeout handler starts a new goroutine when executing the next handler.

Issues:

1. How to prevent the next handler from writing into the ResponseWriter when the ctx's Done channel times out in the timeout handler.
2. How to prevent the timeout handler from replying 408 status code when the next handler is writing into the ResponseWriter but it has not finished yet and the ctx's Done channel times out in the timeout handler.

---

```
package main

import (
  "context"
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
  "time"
)

func main() {
  http.Handle("/race", handlerFunc(timeoutHandler))
  http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func timeoutHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
  const seconds = 1
  ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(r.Context(), time.Duration(seconds)*time.Second)
  defer cancel()

  r = r.WithContext(ctx)

  errCh := make(chan error, 1)
  go func() {
    // w is not safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines
    errCh <- nextHandler(w, r)
  }()

  select {
  case err := <-errCh:
    return err
  case <-ctx.Done():
    // w is not safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines
    http.Error(w, "Request timeout", 408)
    return nil
  }
}

func nextHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
  // just for fun to simulate a better race condition
  const seconds = 1
  time.Sleep(time.Duration(seconds) * time.Second)
  fmt.Fprint(w, "nextHandler")
  return nil
}

type handlerFunc func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error

func (fn handlerFunc) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  if err := fn(w, r); err != nil {
    http.Error(w, "Server error", 500)
  }
}
```

Comment: How about passing something other than the original `ResponseWriter` to `nextHandler()`? You would then have to copy the results back to the original `ResponseWriter` in the `<-errCh` case.

Comment: Whatever is going to write to the ResponseWriter needs to also be responsible for the timeout. You're providing a timeout context to the nextHandler, so that should be able to handle the timeout itself. In general it's easier if only one handler is responsible for writing the response.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution, which is based on @Andy's comment.

A new `responseRecorder` will be passed to the `nextHandler`, and the recorded response will be copied back to the client:

```
func timeoutHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    const seconds = 1
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(r.Context(),
        time.Duration(seconds)*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    r = r.WithContext(ctx)

    errCh := make(chan error, 1)
    w2 := newResponseRecorder()
    go func() {
        errCh <- nextHandler(w2, r)
    }()

    select {
    case err := <-errCh:
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        w2.cloneHeader(w.Header())
        w.WriteHeader(w2.status)
        w.Write(w2.buf.Bytes())
        return nil
    case <-ctx.Done():
        http.Error(w, "Request timeout", 408)
        return nil
    }
}
```

And here is the `responseRecorder`:

```
type responseRecorder struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    header http.Header
    buf    *bytes.Buffer
    status int
}

func newResponseRecorder() *responseRecorder {
    return &responseRecorder{
        header: http.Header{},
        buf:    &bytes.Buffer{},
    }
}

func (w *responseRecorder) Header() http.Header {
    return w.header
}

func (w *responseRecorder) cloneHeader(dst http.Header) {
    for k, v := range w.header {
        tmp := make([]string, len(v))
        copy(tmp, v)
        dst[k] = tmp
    }
}

func (w *responseRecorder) Write(data []byte) (int, error) {
    if w.status == 0 {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    }
    return w.buf.Write(data)
}

func (w *responseRecorder) WriteHeader(status int) {
    w.status = status
}
```